# how to look for a colour and click on it (white colour keeps changing shades) Java

Tags: java, awtrobot

```
import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.Color;


public class main {
  private static Robot robot = null;

  public static void main(String[] args) 
  {
    try {
      robot = new Robot ();
    } catch (AWTException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }

    klick (700 , 118);
    robot.delay(5000);
    colour(700,118);
  }


  public static void klick ( int x , int y)
  {
    robot.mouseMove(x, y);
    robot.delay(5);
    robot.mousePress(MouseEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
    robot.mouseRelease(MouseEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
  }
  public static void colour (int x, int y)
  {
    robot.delay(5);
    Color color = robot.getPixelColor(x,y);
    robot.delay(5);
    System.out.println("Red   = " + color.getRed());
    System.out.println("Green = " + color.getGreen());
    System.out.println("Blue  = " + color.getBlue());

  }
}
```

i want it to find white anywhere on the screen and click it this is what i have so far. 
STEP 1: CLICK ON FIXED POINT
STEP 2: LOOK FOR WHITE COLOUR
STEP 3: CLICK ON WHITE COLOUR
thats all i need help with right now

Comment: So what's the question?

Comment: what do you mean exactly by `then i need it to look for a white colour that keeps changing shades then click on it`?

Comment: its suppose to click on a white portal. you know how portals keeps changing shades?

Comment: Portal as in a portal to another dimension? Mine turn the same colour as the back of my eyelids...Can you clarify the question?

Comment: yes portal to another dimension https://www.google.ca/url?sa=i&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=images&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&docid=cj5ErDt0YlVusM&tbnid=eueCr0sg9-ZFjM:&ved=0CAYQjRw&url=http%3A%2F%2Frunescape.wikia.com%2Fwiki%2FClan_Wars&ei=pvkhU5fdEI_xqQHVnoGwAg&bvm=bv.62922401,d.aWc&psig=AFQjCNFbmpZyzsrXXBff2VWMUlhL8OaqkQ&ust=1394821923088157 like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really understand your question but if you're trying to get the white color to become shaded when you click it (pixel at a time) then you could use this to darken the pixel:

```
public BufferedImage shadePixel(BufferedImage img, int x, int y, int darkness){
//x is the mouse x position & y is the mouse y position

Color color = new Color(img.getRGB(x, y));
int imgR = color.getRed()-darkness;//if it makes it brighter try + instead of -
int imgG = color.getGreen()-darkness;
int imgB = color.getBlue()-darkness;
Color color2 = new Color(imgR, imgG, imgB);

img.setRGB(x, y, color2.getRGB());

return img;
}
```

Hope it helps :)

But if you meant for it to detect the different shades then you could try this:

```
public boolean isShadeOfWhite(BufferedImage img, int x, int y){
Color color = new Color(img.getRGB(x, y));
int imgR = color.getRed();
int imgG = color.getGreen();
int imgB = color.getBlue();

if(imgR == imgG && imgR == imgB){
    return true;
}
    return false;
}
```

Comment: import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Robot;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
    Robot robot = new Robot();

    Color color = robot.getPixelColor(700,118);

    System.out.println("Red   = " + color.getRed());
    System.out.println("Green = " + color.getGreen());
    System.out.println("Blue  = " + color.getBlue());
  }
}

Comment: sorry i dont know to put a code block thing. i used that code to find the colour i was looking for and the values i got were red: 131, green: 115 and blue : 91 ------ i want to find that location and click it

Comment: if the red isn't equal to blue and green than it can't be a shade of white